# Unable to open SQLite DB created in Android (file is encrypted or is not a database)

Tags: android, sqlite, jdbc

Some of my users are reporting that they cannot correctly open sqlite databases created in Android using sqlite jdbc or other tools like sqlite browser (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).

Here is an example database with the problem:

http://pocket-for-android.1047292.n5.nabble.com/Desktop-Version-Screenshots-Work-In-Progress-tp4383220p4456017.html

This sqlite db was created on a HTC Sensation, running Android 2.3.3 and Sense 3.0.

The exact problem is that if you look at the file in a text editor you can see a bunch of tables being created but if you try and run "select * from groups;" you will get an SQLException: file is encrypted or is not a database.

I have tried using "select sqlite_version;" to see if it is a versioning issue - the sqlite browser says 3.6.18.but different tools give me different version numbers... not sure what is going on with that.

I should also point out that my app copies the db directly from the device (/data/data/com.citc.wallet/databases/wallet.db) onto Dropbox.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The db opens fine for me on my PC using SQLiteSpy. Sorry, I know that's no real help for you but I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Yeah - I have just found a tool or two which can also open the db. My best guess is that it is too new a format for sqlite jdbc (http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)

Comment: One idea might be that the newer db uses WAL mode. Try executing 'PRAGMA journal_mode=delete' with a system that works and retry the access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the zentus project is not working with the latest versions of SQLite.

Fortunately someone is keeping a fork maintained here: http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC

All I had to do was replace the jar with the xerial one and it all worked. Xerial sqlite jdbc is in my opinion the best way of connecting to SQLite in Java (I tried several of the libs).

Answer (score -1):

I am also getting the same problem.
But once I have changed the database name it resolved.
So, just try it by creating new database